# How many circular permutations are there of the multiset

Tags: combinatorics, inclusion-exclusion

How many circular permutations are there of the multiset:

$$\{3\cdot{a},4\cdot{b},2\cdot{c},1\cdot{d}\}$$

Answer (score 10):

Note that if you "cut" the circle at whereever you placed the $d$, you just get a regular permutation of the remaining $9$ elements. Any such permutation yields a different circular permutation by adding back the $d$.